# Fetching json data from MongoDB returns an empty array instead of actual data

Tags: arrays, mongodb, fetch, connection-string, is-empty

I am using a connection string to connect to a MongoDB database named `myflixDB2`. I am encountering an issue fetching data from the database. There is clearly data inside my MongoDB, but for some reason an empty array is always returned, as if the collection is empty.

I was expecting to fetch a list of movie titles into my main-view component for my single-page-application. I have checked my connection string and even created a second database, tried interacting with that one instead, still no luck. I have been dealing with this problem for longer than I would like to admit. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

**models.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

let movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Title: {type: String, required: true},
  Description: {type: String, required: true},
  Genre: {
    Name: String,
    Description: String
  },
  Director: {
    Name: String,
    Bio: String
  },
  Actors: [String],
  ImagePath: String,
  Featured: Boolean
});

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Username: {type: String, required: true},
  Password: {type: String, required: true},
  Email: {type: String, required: true},
  Birthday: Date,
  FavoriteMovies: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Movie" }]
});

userSchema.statics.hashPassword = (password) => {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
};

userSchema.methods.validatePassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.Password);
};

let Movie = mongoose.model("movies", movieSchema);
let User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
let Users = mongoose.model("users", userSchema); // Add this line

module.exports = {
  Movie,
  User,
  Users, // Add this line
};
```

**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const Models = require('./models.js');
const { Movie } = Models;

const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.dlxbnnp.mongodb.net/myflixDB2?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0';

// Connect to MongoDB with error handling
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err));

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:63239'
}));

// Define routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the best movie search app ever! (Maybe)');
});

app.get('/movies', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const movies = await Movie.find();
        console.log('Fetched movies:', movies); // Logging fetched movies
        res.json(movies);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

// Add more routes as needed

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('Listening on Port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Include the query that you're trying. 
And double-check that the query is being sent to the proper database and collection -- mongo is flexible by design, so it doesn't complain if you try to query collections or databases that don't exist.

Comment: In your schema file you need to export a model and then import the model to do the query. You need to post the code where you do this please. It's likely mongoose is querying a collection that doesn't exist based on how you define the model.

Comment: Here is the query that I am trying to execute...

const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://User1:Oxonhill15@cluster0.dlxbnnp.mongodb.net/myflixDB2?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0';

// Connect to MongoDB with error handling
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err));

Comment: The query is sent to the MongoDB database hosted at cluster0.dlxbnnp.mongodb.net, specifically to the "myflixDB2" database.....and as far as I can tell, everything is structured fine

Comment: Please change your username and password to your mongodb cluster because you are making it publicly available in your GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition), when you create a schema it is best practice to use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of the `Schema` class. Update your schema like so:

```js
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Title: {type: String, required: true},
  Description: {type: String, required: true},
  Genre: {
    Name: String,
    Description: String
  },
  Director: {
    Name: String,
    Bio: String
  },
  Actors: [String],
  ImagePath: String,
  Featured: Boolean
});
```

Then when you [compile the model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling) you need to ensure that the first argument to the `mongoose.model()` method is a singular version of the collection name because mongoose uses that to infer the collection name:

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. **Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name**.

Update like so:

```js
const Movie = mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema); 
// This will look for a collection called 'movies' because 'Movie' -> 'movies'
```